# Treatment of large data sets (>1M) in standard objects

Tags: big-object, largedatavolumes

Question: At what point Salesforce tags a standard object as big object?

We are planning to load about 10+ million (one time) records in Asset and Order object and there would be incremental records of 1+ million records every quarter.

I would like to understand if Salesforce tags these objects as Big Objects if the transaction records grow at a rapid pace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't.

Standard objects and [Big Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object.htm) are separate kinds of database entity. Big Objects are custom objects you can create to store massive amounts of data, while accepting certain limitations on your ability to query and manipulate those records in exchange.

What you're referring to is [Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_introduction.htm). Large data volumes in non-Big Object Salesforce objects, such as Asset and Order, demand careful consideration of your architecture, querying and reporting strategy, and automation to ensure your org remains functional and performant. The document linked here is a good place to start understanding these concerns.

To quote from the linked documentation,

> A “large data volume” is an imprecise, elastic term. If your deployment has tens of thousands of users, tens of millions of records, or hundreds of gigabytes of total record storage, you have a large data volume. Even if you work with smaller deployments, you can still learn something from these best practices.

Comment: `FieldHistoryArchive` is a standard Big Object, the only one we know about..but perhaps there are others.

Comment: Thank you @David. This information is much helpful.